# Java MessageDigest providing 31 bit instead of 32 bit

Tags: java, md5

I am trying to generate the MD5 hashcode using MessageDigest in java. Please find the sample code below. The String I am trying is combined with some code (KO00001) and system date.

```
String s = "KO00001"+"25/10/2012";
byte[] buffer = s.getBytes();
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md5.update(buffer);
String str = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest()).toString(16).toUpperCase();
System.out.println(str+"    length:"+str.length());
```

I am getting the length as 32 for all the string like KO0000126/10/2012, KO0000126/10/2012. But for the string "KO0000125/10/2012" the result length is 31.

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is all this `BigInteger` calculation about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend [`org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex()`](https://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#md5Hex%28byte%5b%5d%29) for this task.

Comment: Thanks Tichodroma. Spring also having the DigestUtils. I used it.

Answer (score 3):

It is just because of the number, which you get from the byte-array representation of the hashcode using `BigInteger`, is less than others by one position. In other words, the first (high) digit in this representation is `ZERO`.
Just compare:

```
KO0000125/10/2012:
10 radix: 14105476919805249323079848858308382190    length:38
16 radix: A9C9DB4AA1D19A4126E63A7ECFD0DEE    length:31

KO0000124/10/2012:
10 radix: 132805232305710448716177011414649345991    length:39
16 radix: 63E95B7C6574B57A3FD202484D0D17C7    length:32

KO0000126/10/2012:
10 radix: 256722737628903394348650044729556126214    length:39
16 radix: C123003325E6846E04656C2F3E7ECA06    length:32
```

Answer (score 2):

`md5.digest()` **is** 16 bytes.

I suspect that you then try to output it as a 32 character hex string.

For that purpose you should do something like.

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    if (bytes == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("byte array must not be null");
    }
    StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer(bytes.length * 2);
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        hex.append(Character.forDigit((bytes[i] & 0XF0) >> 4, 16));
        hex.append(Character.forDigit((bytes[i] & 0X0F), 16));
    }
    return hex.toString();
}
```

And the result is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`

(edit 1: or as Tichodroma suggested: do not re-invent the wheel, use Apache Commons Codec. Actually the answer to a lot of these questions is 'check Apache Commons first')

(edit 2: do not use getBytes() without specifying an encoding)